# How to add quotes to the start and end of a link in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with links and I want to add quotes to the end and start of the quotes. This is how my df looks like:

```
links
https://us.search.yahoo.com
https://us.search.google.com
https://us.search.wikipedia.com
```

I want my output to be:

```
links
'https://us.search.yahoo.com'
'https://us.search.google.com'
'https://us.search.wikipedia.com'
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you please include your code?

Comment: `df["links"].apply(repr)`. `repr` returns a printable representation of objects - for strings, it adds the single quotes you want (assuming there aren't single quotes interior to the urls).

Comment: Added to my answer, nice one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was curious about the impact of using the inefficient `apply` method here~

Given:

```
                          link   text                      title
0  https://us.search.yahoo.com  Yahoo  Yahoo Search - Web Search
```

I explode its size to 1 million rows:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*int(1e6), ignore_index=True)
```

And then run some timing tests:

```
%timeit df.link.apply(repr)
93.5 ms ± 2.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit "'" + df.link + "'"
68.3 ms ± 1.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

It's clear that the vectorized version of this, `"'" + df.link + "'"` is significantly faster, but it's unlikely to make a practical difference unless your dataframe is insanely large.

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively crude but given you've not supplied an example it's the best I can come up with;

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'link': 'https://us.search.yahoo.com', 'text': 'Yahoo', 'title': 'Yahoo Search - Web Search'}, index=[0])
print(df["link"].apply(repr))
```

Output:

```
'https://us.search.yahoo.com'
```